# encode string aes-128 ecb in golang and decrypt in js

Tags: javascript, go, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt string on golang server, i have a aes-128 encrypt util

```
func EncryptAES(key []byte, plaintext string) (string, error) {
    // create cipher
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // allocate space for ciphered data
    out := make([]byte, len(plaintext))

    for i := 1; i <= len(plaintext)/16; i++ {
        tempBuf := make([]byte, 16)

        offset := (i - 1) * 16
        limit := offset + 16
        // encrypt
        c.Encrypt(tempBuf, []byte(plaintext[offset:limit]))

        for j := 0; j < len(tempBuf); j++ {
            out[offset+j] = tempBuf[j]
        }
    }
    // return hex string
    return hex.EncodeToString(out), nil
}
```

and after that i am trying to do something like that

```
    hasher := sha256.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(word))
    sha := hasher.Sum(nil)

    cypherText := word + userSessionKey

    for len([]byte(cypherText))%16 != 0 {
        cypherText += "0"
    }

    sha128 := sha[:len(sha)/2]

    captchaKey, err := utils.EncryptAES([]byte(hex.EncodeToString(sha128)), cypherText)
    if err != nil {
        SendErrorResponse(ctx, fasthttp.StatusInternalServerError, []byte("error generating aes session key "+err.Error()))
        return
    }
```

but for this key and ciphertext i am getting this error on encryption/decryption aes site
[image]

js func for decoding not working too

```
async function decryptAES128(key, cipherText){
    let hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(key).toString();
    hash = hash.substring(0, hash.length/2);

    console.log(hash);
    console.log(cipherText)

    const bytes = await CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipherText), CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash), { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });

    return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(bytes.words)
}
```

just prints nothing

Comment: Encoding and padding do not match, the ciphertext is not Base64 encoded, the plaintext was not padded with PKCS#7, s. here: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'8eae90e5e96cb43c8dea5e3a572ec4e3'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'ECB/NoPadding','Hex','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=NDZlZjcwYzExOTNmYTI5MDI0NTk1OTY0YTBlYjAxNTdjNGU2NjAyZGE2YzE0MjlmOGEyYjgxMTQ2Zjc5ZTc5OA

Comment: @Topaco ok, thanks, for golang it is working fine. But what is wrong with js script? I am parsing ciphertext and key as a hex but there is just incorrect byte array

Comment: There are some bugs in the CryptoJS code, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go code pads with 0x30 values if the size of the plaintext (`cypherText`, a misleading term by the way) is not an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES). As key the UTF-8 encoding of the hex encoding of the first 16 bytes of the SHA256 value of the password (`word`) is used. The ciphertext is hex encoded.

Decryption with the [online tool](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) fails because the online tool uses PKCS#7 padding and the ciphertext is Base64 decoded. For decryption to be possible, the default PKCS#7 padding must be disabled and the ciphertext must be hex decoded, see e.g. [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%278eae90e5e96cb43c8dea5e3a572ec4e3%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27ECB/NoPadding%27,%27Hex%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)Decode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27)&input=NDZlZjcwYzExOTNmYTI5MDI0NTk1OTY0YTBlYjAxNTdjNGU2NjAyZGE2YzE0MjlmOGEyYjgxMTQ2Zjc5ZTc5OA).

Decryption with the JavaScript code fails because CryptoJS uses PKCS#7 padding by default, the key is hex decoded, and the ciphertext is not passed as `CipherParams` object. For decryption to be possible, the default PKCS#7 padding must be disabled, the key must be UTF-8 encoded, and the ciphertext must be passed as a `CipherParams` object:

```js
var password = 'день';
var key = CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString();
key = key.substring(0, key.length/2);

var ciphertext = '46ef70c1193fa29024595964a0eb0157c4e6602da6c1429f8a2b81146f79e798'
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext)}, // Fix 1: pass a CipherParams object
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), // Fix2: UTF-8 encode the key
    { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }); // Fix 3: disable padding
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

gives as decrypted, UTF-8 decoded data: `деньBvFGlrXeWCnPTwFC00000000`.

---

Security: ECB does not use an IV and is therefore insecure. Nowadays, authenticated encryption is applied (e.g. GCM), but at least a mode with an IV (e.g. CBC).
Furthermore, it is insecure to use a digest as key derivation function (KDF). There are dedicated functions for this (e.g. Argon2 or PBKDF2). Also, the byte string of the KDF should be used directly and not the UTF-8 encoding of the hex encoding, which reduces security.
The 0x30 padding applied is generally unreliable. More reliable is e.g. PKCS#7 padding.